# Cannot get the previous status command in ssh bash using Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I am working in a Pipeline using Jenkins.

I want to run some tests in a docker container that I have running in a device, using ssh with the following command:

```sh
echo 'balena exec <container> nosetests tests/ ;exit;' | balena ssh <UUID>
```

The problem that I have is that, even if the tests fails, the status code of the ssh command is going to be 0, because the code has been executed.

if I print the status code for each of the executions:

```sh
echo 'balena exec <container> nosetests tests/: echo $? ;exit;' | balena ssh <UUID>; echo $?
```

the output that I obtain is:

1 for the first echo and 0 for the second echo.

This is how I have write the stage where Jenkins is executing and retrieving the status code:

```
stage('stage name'){
    agent { node { label 'master' } }
    steps{
         
           script {
                   status = sh(script: 'echo "balena exec <container> nosetests tests/; exit;" | balena ssh <UUID>',  returnStdout:true)

    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the status that I obtain inside of the device and put it into the variable status in jenkins?

A suggested in the commends, if I try to do:

```sh
balena ssh <UUID> 'balena exec <container>  nosetests tests/'
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find a service balena exec <container> nosetests tests/ on device <UUID>.
```

Comment: in command chain like "echo 'balena exec <container> nosetests tests/ ;exit;' | balena ssh <UUID>" you will receive status of the latest command executed. 
On local PC it sill be "balena ssh" (whatewer it is). 
On remote PC it will be "exit"

Comment: Can you use `balena ssh <UUID> 'balena exec <container> nosetests tests/'` ? I believe that might solve your problem (no need for exit -> the return code is now the one of the `balena exec` command)

Answer (score 0):

When you use two or more commands with pipe between them:

- `$?` contains the return code of the last command
- the `PIPESTATUS` array contains all return codes for all commands

So, in :

```sh
echo .... | ssh ...
```

The `PIPESTATUS` contains the return codes for `echo` and `ssh`.

- `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` contains `echo` return code
- `${PIPESTATUS[1]}` contains `ssh` return code

If you want to read more than 1 value:

1. Make an array copy first
2. Read the array copy

```sh
echo .... | ssh ...
PIPESTATUS_COPY=(${PIPESTATUS[@]})
echo "PIPESTATUS[0]=${PIPESTATUS_COPY[0]}"
echo "PIPESTATUS[1]=${PIPESTATUS_COPY[1]}"
```